# How Broad Should the "Scope of Access", Assigned to Personal Access Token in AzureDevops, Used for GIT Be?

Tags: linux, git, authentication, azure-devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## Background

I am attempting to using the `git` command line utility on WSL and Linux to access GIT repositories on Azure DevOps. According to Microsoft documentation found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate).

> For non-Microsoft tools that integrate into Azure DevOps but don't support Microsoft account or Azure AD authentication, you must use PATs. Examples include Git, NuGet, or Xcode.

A *PAT* is a Personal Access Token.
A *PAT* allow for 30+ *scopes of access* and a *scope* has multiple sub-options.
For clarity I am referring to this form.[image]

## Question

Besides the *code* scope (which is obvious), are there any other permissions/scopes which should be enabled for `git` to be fully functional when interfacing with Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you dont need any other scopes to work with the repo. I'm also quite certain you dont need manage permissions, but I didnt test this hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the detail information about all scopes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes). What scope you can set is detailed in the scope list. If you use GCM on linux to connect remote Git repository hosted in VSTS, the GCM will open a web browser window so that you can authenticate and authorize access to your account, it will create a PAT scoped for vso.code_write, effectively granting Git permission to read and write to your Git repositories hosted in VSTS. I am not sure `fully functional` in your post means full access.